# JDBC No Suitable Driver found Even Though .jar Files are added to the Class Path and Dependencies

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc

I'm working on a Project in Android Studio which includes a MySQL Database. 
I'm trying to connect to it with the following code:

```
package com.example.touristguide.dbanbindung;
import com.example.touristguide.klassen.LocationData;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class DbConnection {



private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://censoredsqlhost.net:3306/dbname";
private static final String user = "user";
private static final String password = "password";

private static Statement stmt;
private static Connection conn;

public DbConnection() {

}

private static void getConn() {
    try {

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n CONNECTION"+conn.getMetaData()+"\n\n\n\n CONNECTION");

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
/*
 Other Stuff
*/
}
```

But I get the error:

```
2020-01-16 18:20:47.612 5752-5752/com.example.touristguide W/System.err: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://censoredsqlhost.net:3306/dbname
2020-01-16 18:20:47.613 5752-5752/com.example.touristguide W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:594)
2020-01-16 18:20:47.613 5752-5752/com.example.touristguide W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:219)
```

I already added JDBC and MySQL Connector into the class path and added them into the dependencies
I'm looking for a solution for hours but every solution result in the same error.
I also tried different versions of both jdbc and mysql connector, still nothing

Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Already tried that. I just get ClassNotFoundException on that one.

I haven't tried the second one though. I will try it

Comment: okay second one gives me an error:
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/mysql/cj/jdbc/Driver;`

Comment: You really shouldn't be using a JDBC driver from an Android application. Using direct database access is relatively insecure, poorly performing and generally just not a good idea. You should use a rest service to mediate between your application and the database. Also, as far as I'm aware, recent MySQL Connector/J version will not work on Android because certain required classes are not available in Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use [this connector](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.18). You'll see a table with "License", "Organisation" etc. and look for the "File" field and you'll see a clickable "jar" file which will automatically download for you the connector. If you're using "pom.xml" in your project, you can copy and paste the maven dependency without downloading the jar file.

EDIT: Sorry, I didn't see that this is an Android project. Add in your gradle file this dependency:

> compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.18'

Comment: Nope Still the same Error

Comment: Okay tried it:
compile Group gives me an error "Run Tasks:app:mergeDebugJavaResource" with the message "More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/README'" 
Also Android Studio tells me about "compile" that is deprecated and should be replace with implementation.

Comment: Yes, the compile is deprecated, you could replace it with implementation, but I'm not really sure if it'll make any difference. If you've added any jars to your project, try to delete them and build the project only with the dependency in your gradle file.

Comment: Still get the above mentioned error with OS Independent path. 

Here is waht my dependencies look like, maybe I screwed something up
[link](https://pastebin.com/fPmpwv76)

Comment: try remove these two :
implementation project(path: ':sqljdbc42')
implementation project(path: ':mysql-connector-java-8.0.18')

Comment: Okay that worked so far, but now I get a different Error

`2020-01-16 23:06:07.815 875-875/com.example.touristguide W/System.err: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.`

Comment: Maybe some of the database properties are incorrect. Are you sure that 
"censoredsqlhost.net:3306" is available for you to connect ? Usually if you're trying to connect to a local database this should look like this : "localhost:3306". And check the user and the password too,  I think that most of the MySQL servers come with "root" user, empty password and "localhost:3306" url.

Comment: it's from a free online MySQL hosting site. Maybe you are right. We already requested a private MySQL Server from our University. I will try it again with that. 
If it's still there I will just make it another question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem. Anytime :)